# Android EditText specifically for URL

Tags: java, android

I would like to make an EditText field in an Android application asking the user to give a URL.
I noticed when you type a URL in the "Internet" application, a keyboard that has "www." and ".com" buttons appears .

How can I make my EditText pop that keyboard instead of the regular one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use below code for EditText

```
 android:inputType="textUri"
```

Comment: any idea why it's ur _i_ ?

Comment: @AnchithAcharya because URL is a subset of [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), meaning URL is a type of URI...so having the EditText support all kinds of URIs makes it more flexible